# Finding the index of a specific element in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have searched everywhere to find an answer for this and have come up with nothing!

I have a data file containing two columns, one with wavelengths in nanometer (some with decimal digits, others just with a decimal point) and the other with spectral irradiance values.

I am trying to make a new table that takes as the first column all the wavelengths and in the second column I divide the spectral values by photon energy to get photon flux. However, in this new table I want to stop at a certain index i where the wavelength corresponds to a specific photon energy that I calculated. This is the code I use. It works.

Here is a small portion of the data table:

```
{280., 280.5, 281., 281.5, 282., 282.5, 283., 283.5, 284., 284.5, \

SSpecUsed = Drop[Table[{SSpecWavelength[[i]],SSpecIntensity[[i]]/Eph[SSpecWavelength[[i]]]*Subscript[En, G, Si]*q /. numval}, {i, 0, 949, 1}], 1];
```

My issue is that I manually found the index (949) at which the wavelength is 1107. nm. In a later exercise I need to integrate over this data up to different indices (so for example integrating all the way up to wavelength 2000 and in the next step only up to 1999). So I tried replacing the 949 value by:

```
Position[SSpecWavelength, Subscript[\[Lambda], G][Eg_]]/.numval
```

So basically I try using Position to find the index at which the element in the list is equal to the wavelenght that I calculate based on an energy value. When I run it I get empty curly brackets. I even tried this:

```
Position[SSpecWavelength, 1107.]
```

and I still get empty curly brackets. I checked and I know for a fact that the element at index 949 is equal to 1107. so why does it not return me the index?

Is there another (better/simpler) way to accomplish what I want?

Thanks in advance, hope the problem is clear!

Comment: Would you please provide a small portion of the data table as an example? That would make live much easier for us.

Comment: You may try something like `FirstPosition[SSpecWavelength, _?(# > 1107. &)]` to find the first position with a value larger than `1107.`.

Comment: In general `Position` may take floating point numbers more literate than you. The value from the list could be `1107.0000001` or so but only the leading digits are shown. This difference may be small, but `Position` won't match `1107.` with `1107.0000001`.

Comment: FirstPosition works actually. But why does Position not work? The element in the list is exactly 1107.

Comment: How do I only use the returned index number without the curly brackets? How do I remove the brackets?

Comment: With `FirstPosition[SSpecWavelength, _?(# > 1107. &)][[1]]`?

Comment: Thanks you are the best!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given

```
data = {280., 280.5, 281., 281.5, 282., 282.5, 283., 283.5, 284., 284.5};
```

you could use

```
data[[;; Position[data, 282.][[1, 1]]]]
```

or

```
data[[;; FirstPosition[data, 282.][[1]]]]
```

both return

> `{280., 280.5, 281., 281.5, 282.}`

I recommend that you use the 2nd form; i.e., the one using `FirstPosition`

Now suppose `data` was

```
data = {280., 280.5, 281., 281.5, 282.0000001, 282.5, 283., 283.5, 284., 284.5};
```

Then, although

```
data[[5]]
```

prints out as

> `282.`

```
Position[data, 282.][[1, 1]]
```

generates the error message

[image: msg]

To fix this you can write

```
Position[data, _?(Round[#, .1] == 282. &)]
```

> `{{5}}`

The same change in its 2nd argument will fix the problem should `FirstPostion` be used in place of `Position`.

Comment: `Extract[]` might be less cumbersome to use than `Part[]` in this case.

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less. Could you expand on that. I can't see any nice way to use `Extract` because I can't see any equivalent of `Span` which makes using `Part` so convenient..

Comment: Ah, I was thinking of the usage like in the second part of your answer, where you have isolated positions. If you want to use `;;` then `Part[]` is indeed the better choice (or `Take[]` for that matter, since `list[[ ;; n]]` and `Take[list, n]` should both do).